# PayPal not returning variables

Tags: php, paypal

I'm adding PayPal to my checkout form. Rather than using the API, I just use a form script. However, I'm not getting the response variables from PayPal after the payment has been made. I would like to confirm the amount of money I received to see if the user has paid the amount he should've paid.

Since I dont receive the response variables from paypal, I cannot see whether the user has indeed paid the good amount of money. Am I doing something wrong? I see alot of people have problems with it and none of them had the answer.

My form:

```
<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" >
                        <input type="hidden" name="business" value="seller@seller.com">
                        <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
                        <input type="hidden" name="upload" value="1" />
                        <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="<?php echo $_amount_credits ?> credits">
                        <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="<?php echo $_invoice_id ?>">
                        <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="<?php echo $_total_amount ?>">
                        <input type="hidden" name="lc" value="NL">
                        <input type="hidden" name="rm" value="2">
                        <input type="hidden" name="cbt" value="Go back to http://domain.com">
                        <input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="1" />
                        <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="EUR">
                        <input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://domain.com/index.php?payment=success&transaction_id=<?php echo $_GET['tx'] ?>"/>

                        <input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="http://domain.com/index.php?payment=canceled&transaction_id=<?php echo $_GET['tx'] ?>"/>
                        <input type="submit" class="button blue _quick_order_overview _payment_paypal" name="submit" value="Pay via PayPal">
                    </form>
```

Comment: Where's the code for your receiving page?

Comment: @Kkinsey The receiving page is the same page where the form is located. I'm checking whether the $_GET variables are set. If they are, show success content, if not show the paypal button. 

I was thinking about making a callback page where I'm gonna do the db stuff. But then again, I cant validate if the payment has been made and how much they paid.

Comment: Right.  I'm not sure if I'm explaining this well, but I think you're looking in the wrong place for "tx".  **After** your user submits the form above, which is for submission of your cart, PayPal will return them and automatically append tx=somevalue to the return URL.  You can't _**send**_ them the value for "tx" because you're not *supposed* to have it yet.

Comment: PayPal does not return anything, thats the point. I added the variables just to check if I could get an answer. If I remove the variables, it just redirects me to the index.php with no variables what so ever..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [Instant Payment Notification (IPN)](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNIntro/) for this sort of thing.  There are lots of good templates for this available on GitHub/Packagist, etc.

IPN will POST transaction data to a listener script you have setup on your server any time a transaction happens on your PayPal account.  This would be for payments, refunds, disputes, cleared e-checks, etc.  You can automate all sorts of tasks based on the different txn_type's that IPN sends you.